# How to resize an input box in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have create an input box in java script like this: `text.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));`

i try to re-size with: `text.size = '10';` 
but it is not working

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i trying to do a form with java script and i want to put a input box for comments and increase the size to do like a text area..

Comment: Quentin's answer is appropriate but you should be using CSS for this, not the `size` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size` is a property of the `<input>`. You're trying to apply it to the container you put the input in.

You need to either keep a reference to the input (by assigning it to a variable instead of passing the return value of `createElement` to `appendChild`) or find a new one (e.g. through `getElementsByTagName`) and set the size on *that*.